# How to use Interactive Rebase in SourceTree 1.6

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have read that [Sourcetree 1.6 (Mac)](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2013/05/07/sourcetree-for-mac-1-6/) has the new feature "Interactive Rebase".
My problem is to find this dialog in the Sourcetree App.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest (June 2014) Atlassian article "[Interactive rebase in SourceTree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/06/interactive-rebase-sourcetree/)" does illustrate where to find that feature:

> There’s two ways to rebase interactively:

- The first is to right-click (or context-click) on a commit and hit `Rebase children of``interactively…`
- and the second is to hit the `Repository` menu and go to `Interactive rebase`.

[image: http://atlassian.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/rebase-options-soucetree.png]

Answer (score 12):

If you right-click on any commit and there will be a menu item:

```
Rebase children of {commit hash} interactively...
```

You can also go to the Repository menu and click Interactive Rebase which is not commit-specific.

Comment: @northben I'm actually working on it right now, it'll be in 1.5. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

To build on @funrob's answer, you can also hit the "Repository" menu and go to "Interactive Rebase". The difference is that the repository menu's option will rebase from the upstream commit on the current branch. Context-clicking will allow you to rebase on pushed commits so you need to be careful doing that.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Kieran! When the Interactive Rebase feature was announced I had a hard time locating it. I probably ended up finding this question looking for your answer!

Comment: @funrob It's difficult both trying to expose all the features available and also keeping the product clean. I think interactive rebase keeps that balance quite well and is available in the most obvious place, too. You can always check the docs (we're trying to create more at the moment to help people out)

Comment: I'm not following the statement "rebase from the upstream commit on that branch". Please explain deeper. These two selections are clearly very different.